# What is the best way to manage keypairs in EC2?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Let's say you have a team of 3 developers and you want them all working on the same application. Is it advisable to create a keypair such as "mycoolapp.pem", then distribute it privately to the team members so they're all using the same key to log in to the box? What are the best practices for managing keypairs in a team setting using Amazon AWS services? What are advisable ways to store keypairs in a safe place for new team members that come on board that may need access?

thanks

Comment: First of all, do you need to grant them SSH access? What kind of activity your users are going to have?

Comment: yes, assume all 3 developers will be working on the machine or would need to. E.g. if one person has the private key and they're on vacation what would happen

Comment: Then share key... This article might be useful for you: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-add-identity-private-key-for-rsa-dsa-authentication/

Comment: What if one of them gets fired or leaves the company for a competitor?  In that situation you'd want to just revoke one of the keys, so a shared key would not be advisable. Can you have them each generate their own private key, send you the public keypair, and then you add the public half into EC2?